# How to retrieve previous two groups using sql

Tags: sql, oracle, data-analysis

[image: Click to view image]

I would like to find out 21-jan-2022 belongs to which group and
prior to that group if there are any groups present, pull last 2 groups
and the date range.

In this example : 21-Jan-22 falls under G4, so we need to pull out date range of G2 and G3

I am stuck figuring out how to pull out previous two date ranges.

I tried cross join, analytical function, sub-query but still stuck in figuring out the previous two groups.

Comment: Please don’t link to images. Add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with:

```
 with my_table as (
                   select to_date('07/01/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY') as trans_date, 'G1' as group_1 from dual union all
                   select to_date('08/01/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY') as trans_date, 'G1' as group_1 from dual union all
                   select to_date('09/01/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY') as trans_date, 'G1' as group_1 from dual union all                   
                   select to_date('10/01/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY') as trans_date, 'G1' as group_1 from dual union all                   
                   select to_date('11/01/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY') as trans_date, 'G2' as group_1 from dual union all
                   select to_date('12/01/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY') as trans_date, 'G2' as group_1 from dual union all                   
                   select to_date('13/01/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY') as trans_date, 'G2' as group_1 from dual union all
                   select to_date('14/01/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY') as trans_date, 'G2' as group_1 from dual union all
                   select to_date('15/01/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY') as trans_date, 'G3' as group_1 from dual union all                   
                   select to_date('16/01/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY') as trans_date, 'G3' as group_1 from dual union all
                   select to_date('17/01/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY') as trans_date, 'G3' as group_1 from dual union all
                   select to_date('18/01/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY') as trans_date, 'G4' as group_1 from dual union all                  
                   select to_date('19/01/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY') as trans_date, 'G4' as group_1 from dual union all
                   select to_date('20/01/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY') as trans_date, 'G4' as group_1 from dual union all
                   select to_date('21/01/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY') as trans_date, 'G4' as group_1 from dual
                  )
            select *
              from (
                    select * 
                      from (
                            select a.group_1, 
                                   min(a.trans_date) as start_date, 
                                   max(trans_date)   as end_date
                              from my_table a
                             group by a.group_1
                             order by 1
                           ) x
                     where to_date('21/01/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY') not between x.start_date and x.end_date
                     order by 1 desc 
                   )
            where rownum < 3       
            order by 1;
      
GROUP_1 START_DATE END_DATE  
------- ---------- ----------
G2      11/01/2022 14/01/2022
G3      15/01/2022 17/01/2022
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, to get the first and last dates in each group and to get the groups before `2022-01-21` you can use:

```sql
SELECT "GROUP",
       MIN(trans_date) AS start_date,
       MAX(trans_date) AS end_date
FROM   table_name
HAVING MAX(trans_date) < DATE '2022-01-21'
GROUP BY "GROUP"
ORDER BY end_date DESC
FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (trans_date, "GROUP") AS
SELECT DATE '2022-01-06' + LEVEL,
       CASE
       WHEN LEVEL <=  4 THEN 'G1'
       WHEN LEVEL <=  8 THEN 'G2'
       WHEN LEVEL <= 11 THEN 'G3'
       WHEN LEVEL <= 15 THEN 'G4'
       END
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 15;
```

Outputs:

| GROUP | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| G3 | 2022-01-15 00:00:00 | 2022-01-17 00:00:00 |
| G2 | 2022-01-11 00:00:00 | 2022-01-14 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8_g4ObmH)

Answer (score 0):

```
select group_name, min(trans_date), max(trans_name)
from x_table
group by group_name
order by group_name
```

This would produce the result you have shown in that picture. Again, I do not have the DDL for your table. And I don't know whether a column in an Oracle table may be named GROUP, like you gave in that picture, seeing that GROUP is a SQL keyword, used in group by.